# How to Start With Updated Packages In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I create a new project in Unity, I see the warning at the bottom saying:

`Visual Studio Editor Package version 2.0.14 is available, we strongly encourage you to update from the Unity Package Manager for a better Visual Studio integration` because it is on 2.0.12.

It was fine the first time I went to update it in the package manager, but it's kind of annoying to have to redo it each time I make a new project. How can I tell Unity to give all of my new projects the latest version of a package if they are using it?